# Webpack with ES6: module import policy

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, amd, webpack, commonjs

I noticed that in many sample projects with webpack & ES6 (also in my current) to import an external module `require` is sued instead of ES6's `import`.

Is there any benefit from using `require/module.exports` instead of `import/export` in app bundled with webpack?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I feel that's just a convention. I would stick to `import/export` given it's the new standard.

There's one exception to this rule - [require.ensure](https://webpack.github.io/docs/code-splitting.html#require-ensure). If you want to set up split points, that's what you have to use for now. This will likely change when webpack 2 gets out.